# Optional Value in the UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, option-type

- My Issue:

Please read my description:

Trying to write a model just like the Native Calendar APP of iOS.

Like always, the simple Logic: 12 months = 12 sections, month.days.count = number of cells in the section...

After struggling with Date Calculation and UICollectionView, this little model almost done.

Just One `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping` error made me crazy.

- How to trigger this bug?

Here the thing: We choose the specific date on the Calendar App, and the date we chosen will be highlighted or will have something obvious changed.

For example, if I choose Jan 1st 2016, `Jan 1st 2016 Cell` will be highlighted. Then I choose Jan 2nd 2016(a short period relatively), `Jan 1st 2016 Cell` will switch to Normal State and `Jan 2nd 2016 Cell` highlighted.

For now, there is no error had been triggered.

But if I choose `Dec 1st 2016`, a long period relatively, after I chosen `Jan 2nd 2016`. The App crashed with fatal error.

- We can know

  If we chosen two dates which have long relative period with each other, App crashed. But App run well with short relative period selected.
- We don't know

  How long is this relative period between two selected Dates?

  Which nil-lovely variable(s) make the App crashed?
- The Code:

viewDidLoad():

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Create the dateUnitArr which includes dates of Year 2016, Days of Year 2016 seperated in 12 Months
    for indexOfMonth in 1...12 {
        let numOfEmpty = self.numOfEmptyCell(HeadDayOfMonth: NSDate(year: 2016, month: indexOfMonth, day: 1))
        let numOfMonth = NSDate(year: 2016, month: indexOfMonth, day: 1).monthDays
        self.dateUnitArr.append([NSDate](count: numOfEmpty + numOfMonth, repeatedValue: NSDate()))

        self.selectedUnitArr.append([Bool](count: numOfEmpty + numOfMonth, repeatedValue: false))
    }
    // Allocate values to Days in the dateUnitArr
    for indexOfMonth in 0...11 {
        let numOfEmpty = self.numOfEmptyCell(HeadDayOfMonth: NSDate(year: 2016, month: indexOfMonth+1, day: 1))
        let numOfDays = NSDate(year: 2016, month: indexOfMonth + 1, day: 1).monthDays + numOfEmpty
        if numOfEmpty == 0 {
            for indexOfDay in 0...numOfDays - 1 {
                self.dateUnitArr[indexOfMonth][indexOfDay] = NSDate(year: 2016, month: indexOfMonth + 1, day: indexOfDay + 1)
            }
        } else {
            for indexOfDay in 0...numOfDays - 1 {
                if indexOfDay < numOfEmpty {
                    self.dateUnitArr[indexOfMonth][indexOfDay] = NSDate(year: 2012, month: 1, day: 1)
                } else {
                    self.dateUnitArr[indexOfMonth][indexOfDay] = NSDate(year: 2016, month: indexOfMonth + 1, day: indexOfDay + 1 - numOfEmpty)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

cellForItemAtIndexPath():

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("DateCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        as! CollectionViewCell
    if self.dateUnitArr[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] < NSDate(year: 2015, month: 1, day: 1) {
        cell.strOfMonth.text = ""
        cell.numOfDay.text = ""
        cell.numOfDay.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.numOfDay.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.numOfDay.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        cell.numOfDay.clipsToBounds = false
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
    } else {
        if self.isFirstDayOfMonth(InputDate: self.dateUnitArr[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]) {
            let dateOfCell = self.dateUnitArr[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            let monthOfCell = dateOfCell.monthName
            let index: String.Index = monthOfCell.startIndex.advancedBy(3)
            let shortedMonth = monthOfCell.substringToIndex(index)
            cell.strOfMonth.text = shortedMonth
            cell.numOfDay.text = self.dateUnitArr[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].toString(DateFormat.Custom("dd"))
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = true

            if self.selectedUnitArr[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] {
                cell.numOfDay.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
                cell.numOfDay.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                cell.numOfDay.layer.cornerRadius = 15
                cell.numOfDay.clipsToBounds = true
            } else {
                cell.numOfDay.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                cell.numOfDay.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                cell.numOfDay.layer.cornerRadius = 0
                cell.numOfDay.clipsToBounds = false
            }
        } else {
            cell.strOfMonth.text = ""
            cell.numOfDay.text = self.dateUnitArr[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].toString(DateFormat.Custom("dd"))
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
            if self.selectedUnitArr[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] {
                cell.numOfDay.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
                cell.numOfDay.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                cell.numOfDay.layer.cornerRadius = 15
                cell.numOfDay.clipsToBounds = true
            } else {
                cell.numOfDay.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                cell.numOfDay.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                cell.numOfDay.layer.cornerRadius = 0
                cell.numOfDay.clipsToBounds = false
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

didSelctedItemAtIndexPath(): the bug trigger in Here

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print(self.dateUnitArr[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] + 1.days)
    if self.isSelected {
        // Unmark the SelectedCell
        self.selectedUnitArr[self.selectedIndex.section][self.selectedIndex.row] = false
             let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(self.selectedIndex) as! CollectionViewCell 
        selectedCell.numOfDay.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        selectedCell.numOfDay.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        selectedCell.numOfDay.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        selectedCell.numOfDay.clipsToBounds = false
        // Mark the Neo SelectedCell
        self.selectedIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: indexPath.section)
        self.selectedUnitArr[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] = true
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.numOfDay.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        cell.numOfDay.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.numOfDay.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        cell.numOfDay.clipsToBounds = true
        self.collectView.reloadData()
    } else {
        // Mark the Neo SelectedCell
        self.isSelected = true
        self.selectedIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: indexPath.section)
        self.selectedUnitArr[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] = true
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.numOfDay.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        cell.numOfDay.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.numOfDay.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        cell.numOfDay.clipsToBounds = true
        self.collectView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

[image]

- My Guess:

Maybe problem is about `reuse Cell`?

Please teach me how to solve this problem.

A big appreciation for your guide and time.

Ethan Joe

Comment: When app crashes, type `po collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(self.selectedIndex)` in debugger. It can be `nil`, it can be *not* `CollectionViewCell`.

Comment: Use `as? UICollectionViewCell` instead. Add if else, then add a break point to see for which index path it becomes nil

Comment: Pls try to isolate the problem and create a simple project to replicate the issue. Doing that will help you understand the root cause.

Comment: Reply for 'user1046037': Thanks, `if let` binding works. There is one question: I'm pretty sure `The value` will be not nil after unwrapped. But why it works I unwrapped it after add 'if let' binding?